# User Profile sync with User Information List

Tags: 2007, user-profile, user-information-list

Do these two lists have a syncing mechanism?  I know of the User Profiles being synced via your data store, but does the User Profile sync with the User Information List?  If so, what settings drive that synchronization?

I've found this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/c69069af-9422-436a-9ac8-8f996291de03
And also a contradicting link:
http://blog-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/08/user-information-list-not-synchronised.html

Which one is right?

Comment: I don't know the "right" answer, so I haven't posted here. But my gut says that there's really no need for the User Pofile Store to synch with the User Information List. I think they both pull from other sources.

Comment: The problem comes when someone changes their last name.  It's changed in AD and pushed to the User Profile but the User Info List is still populated with old/stale data.  I'm wondering about the mechanism that syncs the User Info List.  It's a bit of a downer because Jill Jones is now Jill Doe but all of her items still show up as Jill Jones b/c of the User Info List...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this article explains exactly what's going on.  I'm going to give this a whirl.
[User Profile Sync Issues](http://blogs.technet.com/b/nishants/archive/2010/08/23/troubleshooting-user-profile-sync-issues-in-office-sharepoint-server-2007.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [SharePoint AD Sync](http://www.boostsolutions.com/active-directory-sync.html) can tackle this issue pretty well. However, the article you referred above does provide a very neat solution.

Comment: Please update the link it is broken